# How show Highlighted options in react-select

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/home). But I don't know how to get the value of the currently highlighted option from the list options.

E.g. if a user pressed the key down or up button, I want to know which option is selected.

[image: select listbox]

I haven't found any usable props in the documentation.

Not looking solutions like below.
[Get value of highlighted option in React-Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660675/get-value-of-highlighted-option-in-react-select)

Comment: what do you mean? bit confused. you mean that your search text should be highlighted at the select options that are filtered?

Comment: I mean If I search I get list. And User  keyup or down. Highlighted value I need.Update questions with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the library doesn't provide such a feature. However it applies the `[class-prefix]__option--is-focused` to the option that is focused. You can then easily get the value you want by checking classes change in pure Javascript.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53914092/8583669) implement the class `ClassWatcher` that enable you to check class addition or removal on a specific node like:

```js
new ClassWatcher(targetNode, 'your-class', onClassAdd, onClassRemoval)
```

So you could add this watcher to each options of the select by using `querySelectorAll` on the `ref` of the select. First step is to initialised the component with a few options and some states like `isMenuOpen`, `focusedValue` and the `selectedOption`:

```js
const OPTIONS = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [focusedValue, setFocusedValue] = React.useState("");
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState(null);
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Focused value: {focusedValue}</p>
      <Select
        ref={ref}
        classNamePrefix="my-select"
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={setSelectedOption}
        options={OPTIONS}
        isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}
        onMenuOpen={() => setIsMenuOpen(true)}
        onMenuClose={() => {
          setFocusedValue("");
          setIsMenuOpen(false);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now we can use `ClassWatcher` to update the `focusedValue` state when the class `my-select__option--is-focused` change. This as to be done when the `ref` is not null and when the menu is open so we can use a `useEffect` hook for that:

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref && isMenuOpen) {
      const menu = ref.current.select.menuListRef;
      const options = menu.querySelectorAll(".my-select__option");

      // add class watcher to each options
      options.forEach((option, index) => {
        new ClassWatcher(
          option,
          "my-select__option--is-focused",
          () => setFocusedValue(OPTIONS[index].value),
          () => {}
        );
      });
    }
  }, [ref, isMenuOpen]);
```

You can check here the complete example:

[image: Edit nice-feather-di684]

Comment: I didn't get 'select' in 'ref.current.select'. In dom i didn't find class as 'my-select__option'.Even on react-select offical site they dont have this class, when I debugged.

Comment: @MikePhils Did you add the `classNamePrefix="my-select"` prop to the `Select` component? The codesandbox uses `react-select` version4.3.1 and it works properly.

Comment: ref dont have select. Mine is version 2+

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade it because this version is really old.

Comment: Unfortunately not, using in many place in our project

Comment: Ok please next time provide this information in first place. I will try to see how to implement this with this old version.

Comment: My bad 'react-select: 2.4.2'.Basically let say when hit enter then options highlighted selected.Something like that. Example let say If I hit space button then highlighted must selected.

Comment: Mmh just checked with v2.4.2 and it's also working fine, you can see that when you focus an element its value is showned at the top https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-wildflower-ct7tl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: [class-prefix]__option--is-focused this is important.

Answer (score 0):

The Option component has an `isFocused` prop you that could be used.  I'm looking at injecting a ref into the custom option prop and whenever that option is focus, update the ref to the value of that option.

```
import React from "react";
import Select, { components, OptionProps } from "react-select";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

export default () => {
  const focusdRef = React.useRef(colourOptions[4]);

  const Option = (props: OptionProps<ColourOption>) => {
    const { isFocused, data } = props;
    if (isFocused) focusdRef.current = data;
    return <components.Option {...props} />;
  };

  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      components={{ Option }}
      styles={{
        option: (base) => ({
          ...base,
          border: `1px dotted ${colourOptions[2].color}`,
          height: "100%"
        })
      }}
      defaultValue={colourOptions[4]}
      options={colourOptions}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
          console.log(focusdRef.current);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

So here whenever you press the right arrow, you have access to the current focused value.

code sandbox:

[image: Edit codesandboxer-example (forked)]